# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk

/* A simple telephone number database that uses a property list */

> I had run this program many times in eclipse but this is showing me unresolved compilation proble

```
package phoneBook;

import java.io.*;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.Properties;

class meths


{       

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    FileInputStream fin=null;





    try {

        fin=new FileInputStream("PhoneBook.txt");

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e)

    {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }





    String name,number;

    Properties pr=new Properties();





    if(fin!=null)

    {

        try {

            pr.load(fin); fin.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e)

        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }





    void find() throws IOException

    {       

        System.out.println("Enter name to find number");

        name=br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Number is:"+pr.getProperty(number));

    }




    void enter()

    {

        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("PhoneBook.txt");

        System.out.println("Enter name and number:");

        name=br.readLine();number=br.readLine();



        pr.put(name, number);
        pr.store(fout, "Phone Boook");
    }


     void operation()
        {   

            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int opt=0;
            System.out.println("1 for stop operation\n2 for enter new entry\n3 for searching number");


            while(opt!=1)
            {
                // Reading option
                try {
                    opt=br.read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }// Read opearation is complete


                switch(opt)
                {
                case 2: enter();    break;
                case 3: find();     break;
                }
            }
        }
}


public class PhoneBook 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {``
        meths ph=new meths();
        ph.operation();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a great deal of code that is not in any method. Your code will not run correctly until you fix it. The fact that eclipse will try to run it anyway is not going to help with that.

Comment: Actually i am new here and a studdent . will you explain me in detail, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible correction :

```
package phoneBook;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

class meths {
 BufferedReader br;
 FileInputStream fin;
 String name, number;
 Properties pr;
 File file;
 String path = "D:/PhoneBook.txt";

 public meths() {
    file = new File(path);
    pr = new Properties();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //If file doesn't exist, create it and load it
    if (!(file.exists() && file.canRead())){
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File can't be created");
        }
    }
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File can't be read");
        }

    // If file is not empty, load properties
    if (fin != null) {
        try {
            pr.load(fin);
            fin.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Properties not loaded");
        }
     }
  }

 void find() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("\n>Enter name to find number:");
    name = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Number is: " + pr.getProperty(name));
 }

 void enter() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("\n>Enter the name :");
    name = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("\n>Enter the number :");
    number = br.readLine();

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

    pr.put(name, number);
    pr.store(fout, "Phone Boook");
 }

 void choice() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("\n>Enter your choice :");
 }

 public boolean isInteger(String chaine) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(chaine);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

void operation() throws IOException {
    int opt = 0;

    System.out.println("1 for stop operation\n2 for enter new entry\n3 for searching number\n");

    while (opt != 1) {
        choice();
        String value = br.readLine();
        if (isInteger(value)) {
            opt = Integer.parseInt(value);
            switch (opt) {
            case 2:
                enter();
                break;
            case 3:
                find();
                break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
 }

 public class PhoneBook {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    meths ph = new meths();
    ph.operation();
  }
}
```

Console view :

[image]

File :

[image]

In conclusion, I will say you have to work on the basics to understand how work class, constructor, methods and members.